# Get value of Generated TextView from TableRow

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Everyone;

I'm just learned to program Android with Eclipse, and here I have the simple program where I can enter the value from EditText element and print it in to the table, which is programmatically generated with the code below.

When the user clicks the Edit Button, I want to retrieve the value in Col1Txt(TextView) of the same row, and pass it to a variable.

I read a lot of samples in the online, but still not clear for me how to do this. Can anyone help me to complete this program?

Thanks.

```
public void Table_AddItem(Context srcpage,final TableLayout TargetTable, String StrCol1) {
    // Creation row
    final TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(srcpage);
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    // Creation textView
    final TextView Col1Txt = new TextView(srcpage);
    Col1Txt.setText(StrCol1);
    Col1Txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellborder);
    Col1Txt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


    // Edit  button
    final Button EditCmd = new Button(srcpage);
    EditCmd.setText("Edit");
    EditCmd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cellborder);
    EditCmd.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    EditCmd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Add the Code Here

        }
    });

    tableRow.addView(Col1Txt);
    tableRow.addView(EditCmd);

    TargetTable.addView(tableRow);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way for getting a `String` from your `TextView`

```
Col1Txt.getText().toString();
```

Comment: its working, thanks. So I don't need to use getChildAt(1), etc. to retrieve the values from elements generated within the method right?